# How do i make a <div> section invisible when a button is clicked (JS)?

Tags: javascript, html, css

How can I hide a `<div>` section with JS and

```
<div class="alertB1">
<div class="sticky">
<h1> This site is still being built</h1>
<p> Please remember this site is still being built. Click <a href="form1.html">here to report a bug </a>
</div>
</div>
<style>
.sticky {
position: -webkit-sticky;
position: sticky;
}
.alertB1 {
width: 100%;
height: 125px;
background: lightgreen;
}

</style>
```

So I am looking to include a button with:

```
<span id="a33"><button>&times;</button></span>
</div>
</div>
```

How can I get the `<span>` to hide the `<div>` tag?
Thanks,
Ring Games

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `onclick` attribute;

More info: [DOM onevent handlers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Event_handlers#HTML_onevent_attributes)

```css
.sticky {
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  position: sticky;
}
.alertB1 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 125px;
  background: lightgreen;
}
```

```html
<div class="alertB1">
  <div class="sticky">
    <h1> This site is still being built</h1>
    <p> Please remember this site is still being built. Click <a href="form1.html">here to report a bug </a></p>
    <span onclick="document.getElementsByClassName('alertB1')[0].style.display = 'none'" id="a33"><button>&times;</button></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
function onToggle() {
      const ele = document.querySelector(".toggle-div");
      ele.classList.toggle("toggle");
    }
```

```css
    body {
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      align-items: center;
      justify-content: center;
      min-height: 100vh;
    }
    .button {
      position: relative;
      background-color: #4caf50;
      border: none;
      font-size: 28px;
      color: #ffffff;
      padding: 20px;
      width: 200px;
      text-align: center;
      -webkit-transition-duration: 0.4s; /* Safari */
      transition-duration: 0.4s;
      text-decoration: none;
      overflow: hidden;
      cursor: pointer;
    }
    .toggle-div.toggle {
      visibility: hidden;
    }
```

```html
  <body>
    <button onclick="onToggle()" class="button">Click here to toggle</button>
    <div class="toggle-div">
      <h1>Toggle Div on click</h1>
    </div>
  </body>
```